# A comment of mine seems to have disappeared

Tags: discussion, moderators, comments

On a recently popular question I made a comment that pointed the ridiculous use of euphemisms in the question's heading and text rather than using a direct term.  It was partly humorous but also serious comment along the lines of not calling a spade a spade, and certainly wasn't offensive in its language.  At least 6 other people agreed with me enough to up vote that comment.  And while my comment wasn't 100% on topic, neither were a lot of the other comments (which given the subject material was to be expected).

Yet 2 days after my comment was made I now find it missing (including from my account summary).  I can only assume that it was moderated out of existence.  So is this assumption correct?  And if so why would it have been it removed?  I can't see anything in the meta site that would lead me to believe I had stepped over a line.

Comment: I have to assume you are talking about the boob question? The word usage and edits (and edits and suggestions for edits on my answer) was discussed in chat as well. First it was called chest. then it was edited to bosom, and I called it breast, and got edited to bosom as well. and in chat we found almost 300 words for it. I agree with you that ppl are too much walking around the hot porridge... a spade is a spade.

Comment: Dont worry about stepping over a line.Im still here ;)

Comment: @MichaelNielsen What I would have loved to put in my comment (but didn't think of until too late) was what the hell the title of the question would be if the body part was a penis and the desired style of the pic was of Robert Maplethorpe.  I think several heads would have exploded!

Comment: I think it's funny that it ended up being just as euphemistic as the original, but more Victorian-sounding.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure it is an improvement, but I also don't care very much.

Answer (score 1):

No idea of any specifics in your case, it may have been me or another, but comments get moderated out of existence all the time on most of the sites. They may get flagged as obsolete, too chatty, or get spotted by a moderator in passing and cleaned up.

I tend to not delete the chatty ones all that often, but I do delete ones that are suggestions or recommendations for change that are either ignored by the author or already done. If you think something should change, change it, the system is designed for editing. Alternately, if you think it's a community behavior thing, which you seem to suggest, bring it to meta for proper discussion as it's designed for that.

The [comment privilege description](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) has a good explanation, in general, about comment usage.

Comment: Damn ..I was hoping you'd have intimate knowledge of my one specific comment!  My comment may have been construed as something like suggesting a correction although that wasn't my intention (and I wasn't about to get into an edit war).  I suppose I am feeling a sense of frustration as IMHO my comment was reasonable .. yet I turn my back and *poof* .. it's gone with no explanation.

Comment: @PeterM - I wouldn't get wound up about comments, they're not intended to stick around, in general. I did take a look at the question, yours is not the only one removed (and likely won't be the last), but I think that comment is probably more appropriate as a meta topic than as a comment to a question that most of the general membership have stopped visiting. Mind you, I'm not sure that the case comes up enough to warrant worrying about it.

Comment: Don't forget that they can get deleted merely because they disagree with the opinion of the moderator :-)

Comment: @MichaelClark - This is true, we have to take our fun from somewhere... :p Actually, we do it less than some sites. The Pets site, for instance, has heavy comment removal in comparison. For the most part I remove them when they no longer have relevance or don't really add to the Q or A.

Comment: JoanneC: Its not that the gods are capricious, it's that they act invisibly.  At least if your question gets shutdown you have a good chance of knowing why (dupe etc).

Comment: JoanneC: From of Michael's comments (above) it seems there was an edit war going on with this particular question - so my attempts at  editing would have been for naught!

Comment: @PeterM - There was no edit war, it was discussed in chat by some long standing members and a (another) moderator and they came to a conclusion. Edits can still be proposed, but yes, it might get rejected as a consequence of that discussion. At any rate, here or chat is a much better place for this topic than comments on a question or answer in the main site.

Comment: I just wanted to chime in and say I agree with what Joanne has said. Comments are more of an ephemeral aspect of StackExchange. They are not the primary content, and are ultimately intended for short discussions to engage in improving answer quality and content. They often go out of date, and will usually be deleted quietly at that point. Try not to take any personal offense at silent removal of comments, there are countless reasons why that may occur, and most are benign.

Comment: @jrista I'm not taking it (too!) personally.  However one thing I do with comments is to effectively use them as a tag to a question that I am interested in but not confident enough to post an answer.  That way I can go back to my `activity` after the fact and follow the progression of a question without having to remember the title of a question (which may change) and without bookmarking it (as bookmarks aren't sortable by time of adding, and again the title may change).  If there is an alternative method to keeping a list of favorite questions within the SE infrastructure, then I missed it.

Comment: @PeterM - Click the star under the voting arrows to favorite a question. This will then be available in your profile under the favorites link about halfway down the page. Using the comment system as your personal bookmark tool is probably a bad idea...

Comment: I agree with Joanne here...best to favorite the topic with the proper tool, rather than try to use a feature of a public community forum as a personal tool for bookmarks. For that matter, one could also simply bookmark the page in your browser...I think that would be just as effective, if not more, as most browsers now highlight bookmarks to pages that have changed since your last visit.